# Can't Update to 18.04 LTS from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.4, and I cannot update to 18.04 from Software Updater.

I get the message

> The software on this computer is up to date.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: Ubuntu by default doesn't upgrade 16.04.x to 18.04, but offers it when 18.04.1 is released (for maximum stability)

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

Comment: @guiverc, when is that expected to be ?

Comment: Yes you can of course force `do-release-upgrade -d` to 18.04, but its not offered as already stated for stability reasons until 18.04.1 which is scheduled for 26-July -2018 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule)  (18.04 is still marked development-release until 18.04.1)

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS has been released the 26 July so I wonder why it is still not available: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

Comment: any updates I have, I've put on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059924/should-i-be-offered-the-option-to-upgrade-to-18-04-1/1059938#1059938  (last ~eta was given thur 9th august, is still in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. But then I run this command in terminal:

> update-manager -cd

and I got this:

[image: update notification]

Run the above command and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: -d is for development releases (alpha, beta...)

Comment: The release is already downloadable but I can't get upgrade yet !

Answer (score 7):

There is still no information about new release here: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
So it will not upgrade