# Should I be offered the option to upgrade to 18.04.1?

Tags: updates, 18.04

I understand that the first point release of Ubuntu 18.04, namely 18.04.1 is now available and that my system should now offer it as an update.

My current OS version is 16.04.5 LTS. In System Settings/Software and Updates I have set 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' to 'For long term support versions'. I have tried both the main server and the server for United Kingdom, neither offers an update when Software Updater is clicked or via the Ubuntu Software icon.

Can anyone please tell me why I don't get the option of updating to 18.04?

**Edit:**

I don't remember the details exactly, but I think that my last LTS point release update was offered automatically a lot sooner after the published release date than where we are now with 18.04.1.

**Edit 10th August**

It appears that there has been some problem with the update process and that it should be fixed next week, see:

[Ubuntu change log](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html)

**Edit 14th August**
18.04.1 LTS now available from UK server,

Comment: be careful about what you wish for... when it's ready you'll be informed. From what I read, some of the features of the new version will be drip fed into 16.04.nn and on that basis, I'm content to carry on with v16LTS given the continuing problems with 18.

Comment: Yes the upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS does not occur until the .1 release has been out, but the usual procedure is the 'taps' are turned on a few days after the .1 release. Currently we're only hours after it, and not 'days'.

Comment: @Graham what are the continuing problems with 18.04?  (I haven't been paying attention, being content with 16.04.)

Comment: @RonJohn Far too many to mention...

Comment: @Graham Name the two most significant in your opinion; dodging the question doesn't support your argument.

Comment: @Rogem I'm also curious about the issues mentioned by Graham, but the official list is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 was released on 2016-July-21 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) and there were the same complaints then  (*listen to the Ubuntu podcast of that time if you want a refresher; it was where the 'tap' analogy of my answer came from*)

Comment: @RonJohn I am using Ubuntu 18.04 servers in production since April and never got a serious issue. Had a couple of glitches the first days but then they got fixed. Some of my servers have fairly complicated VPN + DNS + routing configurations and they all work well. As usual, take a snapshot of your server, upgrade and see if it works well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS does not occur until the `.1` release has been out. The usual procedure is the 'taps' are turned on a *few days* after the `.1` release. Currently we're only *hours* after the release, not 'days', so the update will not be offered quite yet.

It's mentioned in the [release notes](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000234.html):

> "Users of Ubuntu 16.04 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 18.04.1 via Update Manager."

-- update 2018-08-08 ~04:30 UST/UTC

It may soon be available; if this is the 'critical' bug holding up release (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-menus/+bug/1766890) - it only impacts 16.04 LTS -> 18.04 LTS upgrades. 18.04.1 is stable; it's the upgrade-path that is turned-off..

-- update 2018-08-10 ~10:10 UST/UTC

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html

"*We are working on resolving bug http://launchpad.net/bugs/1766890 which results in a bad upgrade experience when people upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. There is a new version of the dist-upgrader in -proposed and we will be testing it the next couple of days and plan on updating meta-release-lts at the beginning of next week.*"

Comment: It's now the 31st and at least on my server install https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061111/16-04-lts-to-18-04-1-lts-upgrade-no-new-release-found this has not happened, why is there no release date / schedule for when the LTS to LTS upgrades go live?  Rather than a vague and inscrutable "a few days" or "sometime".  Many of us would like to plan LTS to LTS upgrades!

Comment: @MattBashton You can always do it yourself before it's official by `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: I agree with Organic Marble. I tested Ubuntu 18.04 & was happy, so upgraded my 'real' systems some time ago.

Comment: This "answer" is no longer valid, since we really are a few days past the 18.04.1 release and an answer of "Currently we're only hours after it, and not 'days'" is no longer valid.

Comment: I just listened to the latest Ubuntu Podcast which was released earlier today (*my local time*) and it mentions the upgrade notice should be hitting the 16.04 screens "about now as you listen to this" (*rough quote from memory; I listened about an hour ago*). The official statement says "soon", and as a 'fly on the wall' watching the release people are busy.....

Comment: That's weird there is no official for this. As this questions shows it bothers quite a lot of people even it's not really an issue.

Comment: August 4, 9+ days after the .1 release, still getting "no new release found."  Time to redefine "a few" ?

Comment: I noticed today (5 aug 2018): "new release '18.04.1 LTS' available" but only when passing the "--dev" flag! So it seems there's really a problem as this version shouldn't be considered as a dev version.

Comment: It may soon be available; if this is the 'critical' bug holding up release (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-menus/+bug/1766890)  - it only impacts 16.04 LTS -> 18.04 LTS upgrades.  18.04.1 is stable; it's the upgrade-path that is turned-off...

Comment: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html  "*We are working on resolving bug http://launchpad.net/bugs/1766890 which
results in a bad upgrade experience when people upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.
There is a new version of the dist-upgrader in -proposed and we will be
testing it the next couple of days and plan on updating meta-release-lts
at the beginning of next week.*"

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler  what more do you want than the schedule as of August 9th? which I provided in the comment before yours?

Comment: @guiverc you can notify the OP that the famous migration option has been activated ;-) !!!

Comment: I don't see the need; yesterday morning my 16.04 laptop came up with the notice, and it was spot on when they said it would be on 9th August [ETA], ie. "early next week".

Comment: Aug 28: Upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS is available now! `Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64). New release '18.04.1 LTS' available. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still receiving the "No release found" error several days after 18.04.1, this process worked for me to upgrade from 16.04.5 to 18.04.1:

Software & Updates > Updates > Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version > Select "For Any New Version" > Open Software Updater

For some reason, "For long-term support versions" was not notifying me about 18.04.1 LTS.

Once I changed it to "For any new version" I was immediately prompted to upgrade to 18.04.1. The upgrade has run without issue.

Mahalo to deadflowr for originally suggesting this fix here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397703

Comment: If that doesn't work, this command in terminal did the work for me:
`/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk`

Answer (score 0):

Guiverc, you seem to have the best fix on this. You indicated that forcing the upgrade (-d) worked well for you.  Does this still work unattended, or will a relative newbie like me get into difficulties?  Is the "official" release likely to be within an additional day or two so that we should be patient?  Do you have any sense what kinds of problems are holding up the official release?

**Addendum**: I run Ubuntu from a VBox virtual machine.  So I cloned my 16.04 version and ran sudo do-release-upgrade -d.

- **a)**  The update worked and completed without hitch and without any need for user intervention.  All of my most important apps seem to work fine.
- **b)**  There were a number of warnings about configuration files that were missing or directories that couldn't be deleted, but these issues seem to have been dealt with later in the update.
- **c)**  One issue should be noted.  The update program warned me that the xenial R source entry in my /etc/apt/sources file had been commented out, but noted that I could reactivate it after completing the update.  Unfortunately there doesn't seem yet to be a Ubuntu R bionic repository.  Fortunately both R and RStudio appear to be updated correctly within the apps, but I suspect that I won't be told of updates of R by the Ubuntu Update app.  In sum, it seems that using the -d option for the Ubuntu update from 16.04 to 18.04 works well.  But NO GUARANTEES.  Larry Hunsicker

Comment: The way we use our own machines differs, and I like your reasoned approach (particularly test upgrade).  I know nothing about R but you may be right in that you may not get updates going forward (unless the app updates itself completely free of ubuntu, which may create issues in time anyway). `do-release-upgrade` is supposed to remove xenial sources (thru comment).  The "-d" is always there, but there is some reason that Canonical have not made the decision to switch-on-16.04-updates, some reason they still feel staying with 16.04.5 currently is more stable; we just don't know what that is.

Comment: The official CRAN repository has R 3.5 for Bionic have a look here https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ simply adjust your sources list to look at `bionic-cran35/` post install!

Comment: i don't know if you watch this - but i've added comments to my answer with more info... & now an ETA has appeared

Answer (score 0):

The do-release-upgrade command is a Python script. After some digging I discovered that it respects presence of 'DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER' in environment.

Typing:

```
$ export DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1
$ do-release-upgrade
```

results in:

```
[... some lines skipped ...]
metarelease-uri: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
MetaRelease.download()
result of meta-release download: **'<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>'**
NO self.metarelease_information
No new release found.
```

So the core reason seems to be the inability to verify the SSL certificate presented by changelogs.ubuntu.com