# 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS upgrade: No new release found

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, lts, do-release-upgrade

I can't get the 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS upgrade to work, I'm running server.

My current version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

However despite 18.04.1 being released on the 26th of July, at present on the 31st I'm still being informed that there is no new release?

My `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file is:

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

And the output of `do-release-upgrade`:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Update manager core is already installed:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:16.04.13).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

**Note that this question is distinct to the one here [Should I be offered the option to upgrade to 18.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059924/should-i-be-offered-the-option-to-upgrade-to-18-04-1) as that question deals with a GUI/desktop based situation whereas this specifically addresses the issue from a terminal / server angle.**

Comment: Have you tried `do-release-upgrade -d` ?

Comment: My understanding is that will upgrade to the development release:

-d, --devel-release   If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the
                        development release

Comment: There is no space after 'Prompt=lts'? Your repos do have 18.04.1 available?

Comment: The /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file was never edited after install, but regardless it has no white space.

Comment: According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes it states **Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04.1's release expected in late July.**  So chances are it is not available yet and we should just keep checking.

Comment: It's already a few days after release. They should make the date clear so that we can plan upgrade.

Comment: I agree @rosencreuz the ambiguity of the release or not upgrade system is not really fitting with the ethos of a server distro, I would be nice if we had a date.

Comment: @MattBashton You could always ask Canonical themselves as to why the delay on the 18.04.1 upgrade release:  https://www.ubuntu.com/contact-us/form?product=generic-contact-us

Comment: @MattBashton You're welcome!  I also sent them a message asking for what the hold up might be and if they could provide any date that it might happen.

Comment: The cause for the lack of offered release upgrade paths is exactly the same for this and the linked question, i. e. their answers would be or are essentially identical. Thus I'm voting to keep it closed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I disagree, the question is different, upgrading via a different method and the answer could well be different in the command-line context to the GUI based solution, but a seizable section of the community are currently getting the `No new release found.` error so will likely be landing here, at 1,903 views at present it will be useful to others to preserve this QA thread.

Comment: Stack Exchange keeps duplicate questions around as “sign posts” for the exact reason that you bring forth. Your argument has no bearing whatsoever on whether one question should be considered a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @DavidFoerster fundamentally disagree with you, since the command-line solution/approach is different I feel this is a valid addition to the other question, unless the two are merged to account for both usage cases.

Comment: You *did* notice that the answers to both questions (so far) are essentially identical though, didn't you? That's very strong evidence that the underlying issue and thus the essences of the questions are too.

Comment: Yes I agree they have the same underlying issue but this won't make them identical.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04.1's release expected in **early August**.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: 18.04.1 was released on July 26th, a "few days" have already passed.  The point release in early August is for Ubuntu 16.04.5 not the LTS to LTS upgrade.

Comment: C'mon, read! https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes  --->

**Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04.1's release expected in early August.**

Comment: When you follow the link on that page it shows that the release of 18.04.1 was actually on July 26th, i.e., the 'early August' date mentioned on the Release Note page is wrong.

Comment: @Rodrigo all we can take from that statement is that upgrades will be a "few days after" the 18.04.1 point release which as Marijn correctly points out happened on the 26th of July, we're clearly passed the a "few days" point at this time.  The release date has been the 26 of July from some time https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule. What this all points to is the fact Canonical really need to improve the documentation of the date LTS to LTS upgrades will go live, as many of us would like to schedule the downtime this will cause in production environments we wish to migrate.

Comment: @Rodrigo I think you've misread the meaning of this sentence, "18.04.1's release expected in early August" - implies 18.04.1 will be released in early August (which is demonstrably incorrect), and not the LTS to LTS upgrade itself, which is expected to be "a few days after".

Comment: The wiki page used to say "late July" (when 18.04.01 was indeed released). Looks like someone changed the date but not the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes I saw that, but the sentence conveys a different meaning to the action of editing it would suggest, the whole LTS to LTS upgrade release needs far better communication!