# Migrating from 16.04 to 18.04 : Why is the "For long-term support versions" option not yet activated?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, migration, ubuntu-wiki

Edit : Note that it is not yet possible to migrate from 16.04.05 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS. Today is Tuesday, August 7.... The release of 18.04.1 LTS took place on July 26... They must have simply forgotten to enable the "For long-term support versions" option in "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version", in the "Software Updater" options... Someone absolutely must tell them please.

---

This documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades indicates, in the part titled "*Upgrade from 16.04 or 17.10 to 18.04* > **Upgrading Ubuntu Desktops to 18.04 (Recommended)**" that in order to migrate from 16.04 (16.04.5 LTS for me) to 18.04 (18.04.1 LTS in fact), we must confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.

My question is : why not to keep it set at its default value, which is : "For long-term support versions" ? 18.04(.1) is indeed an LTS version ! So this option should *also* enable the migration.

I have another question: in addition to allowing the change from 16.04(.5) to 18.04(.1), what are/will be the other (potentially bad) consequences of choosing the "For any new version" option, recommended by the above documentation?

Am I making a mistake ?

## Important

This migration is really **impossible** when "For long term support versions" is chosen. It's possible when "For any new version" is chosen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81356/discussion-on-question-by-jarsofjam-scheduler-migrating-from-16-04-to-18-04-wh).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the option should say "For any new version" OR "For long-term support versions" (and that page now does say that).

I suspect that a prior page is used as a template, and as 3 of 4 Ubuntu releases are standard  (not LTS), it's easier for the delegated release manager to just copy & paste the prior release page making as few changes as possible which is why it I suspect it doesn't say both (*it'd be a bad idea if your release was say 18.10 and you selected 'For long-term support versions' as you'd miss the mandatory upgrade to 19.04 when it came out*)

Currently the switch (see [Should I be offered the option to upgrade to 18.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059924/should-i-be-offered-the-option-to-upgrade-to-18-04-1)) hasn't been enabled for the 16.04 LTS upgrade to 18.04 LTS so yes, you do in fact need the "For any new version" currently, but it is my belief that this will very shortly change.

**As for the page not using LTS for 18.04**

Ubuntu 18.04 is a LTS. Ubuntu first releases on even numbered years (*in April, except for 6.06 which was June*) are LTS. Again I think that's just copying a prior page, and making the least number of changes possible. *The change I made was the least I felt I could, and I don't think adding LTS for every reference makes it easier to read*.

As for 18.04 & 18.04.1: To me there is no difference between a fully updated 18.04 LTS install, and a fully updated 18.04.1 LTS (*if you ignore that the .1 will have HWE kernel installed; where the 18.04 does not come with HWE kernel enabled/installed*).

Comment: If 18.04 is upgraded to 18.04.1, the HWE kernel will be installed

Comment: it is my belief that that is wrong; if you install 16.04 LTS you stay kernel 4.4 permanently (unless you install/enable HWE), ditto 18.04 LTS with it's 4.15.  If you install the 18.04.1 ISO you have HWE enabled (it'll be the same with 18.04.2 & later point releases), but an original 18.04 LTS install will remain the non-HWE kernel unless changed.  It's new installs with point releases (18.04.1, 16.04.5) that have HWE enabled; so if you don't want it, you have to install the original 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS and have more updates post|during-install.  refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

Comment: actually https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack is a better reference, stating "*These enablement stacks can be installed manually but are also available when installing with Ubuntu LTS point release media*"

Comment: Note that it is not yet possible to migrate from 16.04.05 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS. Today is Tuesday, August 7.... The release of 18.04.1 LTS took place on July 26... They must have simply forgotten to enable the "For long-term support versions" option in "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version", in the "Software Updater" options... Someone absolutely must tell them please.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is not yet possible to migrate from 16.04.05 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS. Today is Tuesday, August 7.... The release of 18.04.1 LTS took place on July 26... They must have simply forgotten to enable the "For long-term support versions" option in "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version", in the "Software Updater" options... Someone absolutely must tell them please.

Comment: I fired off an email just now. Not sure if I'll get a reply but if so I'll post back here.

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if they reply please :-)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix please, let us know if you have got a reply ?

Comment: No reply yet. I really didn't expect one they only reply when I report a bug. Hopefully a blog or newsletter makes an announcement soon. In the mean time the you can clone your 16.04 data and upgrade it to 18.04 for testing using `do-release-upgrade -d` when you are on `LTS` update policy. I've done this 5 or 6 times: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade You should always test the upgrade on a clone to avoid surprises!