# Ubuntu mate 19.10 do-release upgrade returns "No new release found" while trying to upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, mate, 20.04

This is what I get when I try to upgrade mate from 19.10 to 20.04:

```
mae@HP-Compaq-6715b-Ubuntu-MATE:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for mae: 
root@HP-Compaq-6715b-Ubuntu-MATE:/home/mae# do-release-upgrade 

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

No new release found.

root@HP-Compaq-6715b-Ubuntu-MATE:/home/mae#
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release) Specifically the final bullet of https://askubuntu.com/a/1229900/19626

Comment: I'm also unable to upgrade to 20.04. A fresh installation from the iso worked fine on another PC but that's not an option for my main setup.

Comment: [Wait until 20.04.1 (aka "the first point release")](https://askubuntu.com/a/125492/11316) arrives. But I agree, this is rather unfortunate. You can "force" it with `-d`, I think.

Comment: The forcing method is in my answer (which is older than your comment).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to wait until it's unlocked for upgrading, run `do-release-upgrade -dc`. If you get 20.04 run `do-release-upgrade -d` to install.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone.
do-release-upgrade doesn't work for me either from 19.10.  No sign of 20.04 for me.
I am uncertain how soon the update repositories are available.  I assumed from the day of release.
Some have suggested adding the development builds with the -d option but I want the normal update option.

This article suggests upgrades this way will happen a few days after the official release so we just need to be patient I guess.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/125492/11316)) provides the main reason and the other answer _here_ provides the workaround (`-d`).

Comment: This has become available today (7/5/20) properly, without using the dodgy development option via regular software updates, however, the documentation still says it is and should not be installed.  Previous releases never made this an issue.  Someone needs to fix this messy confusion on published vs development.  If it's out it's not development.