# Is it safe installing Ubuntu 20.04 now or do I need to wait until 20.04.1 is released?

Tags: system-installation, dell, acpi, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 is released as final version of the developer builds. I've tried upgrading my Ubuntu 18.04 but it didn't showed any updates. I've read using `-d` while upgrading through terminal causes problems in installing. Can I fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell 5567 laptop by removing Ubuntu 18.04? Does this installation also cause problems?

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 it is not booting up. It is just showing a black screen with this boot message:

```
Firmware bug: ACPI region does not cover the entire command
```

Comment: It may cause problems. New releases always do ;-) But most likely it will get installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release). Note advice to 18.04 users in the final paragraph of https://askubuntu.com/a/1229900/19626

Comment: Who are you, and what's your level of Linux expertise? What's this "safe" concept? What essential programs won't work in 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is recommended to wait until the first point release is launched to upgrade Ubuntu to the latest LTS release, there is nothing wrong with doing a new installation of the latest LTS release after it is officially released.

Regarding the `Firmware bug: ACPI region does not cover the entire command` boot message try switching off TPM and ACPI in the BIOS.

[image: ACPI Configuration in BIOS]
<sup>**ACPI Configuration in BIOS**</sup>

[image: TPM in BIOS]
<sup>**TPM in BIOS**</sup>

Comment: But I've encountered a problem after installing Ubuntu 20.04, it is not booting up. It is just showing a black screen

Comment: Please write down the error message that appears on the black screen and then edit/add it into your question. Especially look for any error message that contains the word `ACPI` as this has already been reported in 20.04.

Comment: I have noticed the error is "Firmware bug : ACPI does not cover all command like that ..."

Comment: Try switching off [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and ACPI in the BIOS.

Comment: Where do I turn off this , I'm having DELL 5567 laptop