# How to get the official, non-development version of Focal Fossa 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, do-release-upgrade, 20.04

I followed these instructions to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

I understand the [final release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) was 2 days ago. However, when I run the following as instructed:

```
Press Alt+F2 and type update-manager -c -d into the command box.
```

The popup shows:

[image: Instructions for development release]

I want the final release, not the development release.  I am following the official ubuntu instructions.  What am I doing wrong?

These are my update settings, which should just be LTS:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official upgrade path will be openwed in a couple of days. You will be notified.

`update-manager -c -d` is a force upgrade. That's why you get this message.

Notification for LTS releases is enabled as you can see on the posted screen. So wait for a notification.