# 19.10 to 20.04 - No new releases found

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

My distro:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

My kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux n552vw 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Updates:

[image]

[image]

Ubuntu 20.04 has been officially released 4 days ago.

### Trying to update

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

### Questions

- Are there any reasons why the system still does not prompt to update?

#### Notes

- I DO NOT want the development version (the `-d` flag) - I want FINAL VERSION.
- Why the official page [states to use](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) the `-d` flag (`update-manager -c -d`)?

Comment: Hi 0leg. 20.04.1 is a point release. system can upgrade to point release only if you dont want d for development..

Comment: If you force the upgrade with `-d`, you **will** get the final version of 20.04. For me it worked well, but the upgrade path is still considered unstable.

Comment: [Read also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release9)

Comment: The release date you mention is the ISO release date. The 'taps' (or a packaged update which goes out to 19.10 boxes that lets them see the upgrade path) usually gets enabled in the next 24 hours (Mon or Tue of following week), but that's after a decision is made that release is *stable* enough. The '-d' is required before that time.