# Can't upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I'm running 18.04. When I try to upgrade to LTS version 20.04 using Software Updater I get message that 19.10 is available.  I've set the upgrade line to "any new version". I've also tried using the command line in the terminal with same results. This has persisted since April 23rd - date 20.04 was released. My system is up to date

Comment: The official upgrade path will be opened in the end of July.

Comment: "Any new release" generally shows the immediate supported release. Even if you try to upgrade to 19.10, it'll fail saying upgrade from bionic to eoan isn't supported. Change the prompt to LTS releases.

Comment: Try update do-release-upgrade to that is 2020 May 25th.
Only '19.10' available.
do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '19.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. Then, In https://fossbytes.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-or-19-10-to-ubuntu-20-04/ I read this:

> Also, even after the stable release, you may not get the upgrade
>   option to Ubuntu 20.04. It may take a week or more than that.

I guess we shoud simply wait a few days.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to upgrade right now then you can try the following:

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d` from the command line or,

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `update-manager-d` to launch the GUI installer.

The `-d` option indicates an update to the development release and allows you to upgrade before the first point release.  This option may not work during the first several days around the final release.

Comment: I've already tried that Didn't work

Comment: I think the advice in the comment from @Pilot6 referring to this post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release) is good advice.  The `-d` option may have some unpredictable results at this point in the release cycle.  The article referenced has some very good information about the whole release cycle process.