# Is it safe to force upgrade with do-release-upgrade -d?

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm waiting for over a week now for getting a pop-up for upgrading my system from 19.10 to 20.04.

Is it safe to force upgrading with the `-d` parameter in `do-release-upgrade`?
I'm getting the following output for `do-release-upgrade -cd`

```
Er wordt gecontroleerd of er een nieuwe Ubuntu-uitgave is
Nieuwe versie '20.04' beschikbaar.
Voer 'do-release-upgrade' uit om naar de nieuwe versie op te waarderen.
```

So it proposes to upgrade to 20.04. Will I then be on a development branch, or just normal?

Or is it better to just wait some more time, until I get a pop-up. Or will this pop-up not be shown until the first point release, as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229900/24931) suggests?

Comment: Back up everything that you cannot afford to lose before starting the release upgrade. If your current system works well you can wait until the **beginning of July** and then do the release upgrade. Do it **before 19.10 passes end of life**. (Users of 18.04.x LTS will reduce the risk, if they wait for the first point release near the end of July.)

Comment: FYI:  the *development* branch is now Ubuntu 20.10 (*gorilla*), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*focal*) is no longer development as it's been released, but the upgrade path hasn't been opened yet (thus the '-d' is currently required if you don't jump to the development branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Comment: I'm still confused. @guiverc so using the `-d` will not switch my system to _development_ brach of 20.10 (_gorilla_) as this upgrade path hasn't been opened yet, but instead just upgrade my system to 20.04 wich is now the _stable_ branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I did the upgrade using `do-release-upgrade -d` and now I'm on 20.04 without problems. 
Output for `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```