# Why is do-release-upgrade not seeing the latest release?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04.

I have my Software & Updates set to `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version`, but I didn't see a notification.

I then ran the following commands, and got some weird output.

```
master@master-desktop:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -cd
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '20.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

master@master-desktop:~$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Why is it not capable of upgrading to 20.04 when the `-cd` flag clearly shows it?

Comment: Because it's an LTS release. See [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release), especially https://askubuntu.com/a/1229900/19626

Comment: Run `update-manager -d` in the terminal to upgrade

Comment: Thanks, Raffa. That worked, and appears to be a solution in the linked question.