# Can we set ON a device which is OFF in the BIOS

Tags: security, bios, webcam, microphone

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 (I'm still waiting for the 20.04 upgrade, it seems to be not available in my country, yet).

In the **BIOS** system of my **Laptop**, I set **OFF** the internal **Webcam** and **Microphone** (because some problems with video playback, it seems to be something related with the slow CPU that machine has).

Whatever, as those devices are set **OFF** in the **BIOS** system... Can we set this **ON** from some Ubuntu line command or something?

It is intended to know about the possibility of some external attack (From the web, as example).

Comment: Ubuntu cannot change BIOS settings. If it's OFF in BIOS, then it's OFF and Ubuntu cannot change it. For 20.04 availability, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1229900/19626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, if the devices is set to `OFF` in your `BIOS`, it is **NOT POSSIBLE** to activate it from the operating system.

ie: In my case if I switch my wireless card to off in the `BIOS`, `rfkill` shows the device is hard blocked (hardware blocked).

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0     blocked   blocked
 1 bluetooth hci0     blocked   blocked
```