# Upgrade Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

Is there any option to update Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS to Xubuntu 20.04 from terminal.

I tried with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but I think that i did just apt update without upgrade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Answer (score 7):

I would always recommend reading the release notes for the release you are wanting to move to, for Xubuntu the release notes are

https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/20.04/release-notes#updates

They however do not have Xubuntu specific release *upgrade* notes, they instead refer you to the Ubuntu 20.04 release notes which are

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

which includes the terminal command (*see upgrading servers*)

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

but I'd recommend you read the release notes first, rather than *copy/paste* this command into your system (*starting with the Xubuntu notes first*). Release notes include a list of known issues which were encountered by *testers* of the system providing warning of issues you may encounter.

If you're willing to wait, you will be offered the opportunity to upgrade your system (*with fewer issues expected*) after the upgrade path is normally opened a few days after the Xubuntu 20.04.1 official release.

Comment: The release notes you provided are a list of 50 programs each having their own release notes.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki I don't understand your point or question. The link I gave was the official release notes, which yes contain links to many programs, and in fact many products (including official flavors, and some unofficial but affiliated products from other companies related to cloud etc).  The official release notes link elsewhere where more specific advice is available (they'd be too long if all details, for all applications, images & flavors (plus their programs etc) were included). We tend to trim/add to our initial install, so our systems tend to be *unique* so we can read what applies

Answer (score 1):

```
apt update
```

is used to check and update your package repository for new versions of your installed packages.

```
apt upgrade
```

is used to "update" those packages to their new versions.

[Here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-to-ubuntu-19-04) is a website that describes the process of manually upgrading to a new distro-release via GUI or command-line