# What happens after upgrading Ubuntu using dev channel?

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, do-release-upgrade, 21.04

recently I upgraded my Ubuntu to 21.04 using dev channel:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

(it was because I was curious of 21.04 and couldn't use `-c` flag because of [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/04/why-you-cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-for-now))

where:

```
-d, --devel-release
              If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
```

Now I wonder, am I using dev version of Ubuntu from now on? I would like to eventually use stable version of 21.04. How do I do that?

Comment: You're using the same 21-04 like everybody else.

Comment: Just keep 21.04 updated :). Does this answer your question? [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

Comment: Anyways, in this case, `-d` does not mean development **release**, but should rather be called *"unsupported upgrade path"*. The question was asked before. E.g.: [Is the “Final Release” a “Development Release”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Comment: Thank you for your responses!