# Software Updater not giving option to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I am anup from delhi ,India and  my server is http://repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu ,since  yesterday (23 april 2020) I have  been trying  to  check and  recheck by clicking on software updater and  unfortunately  it is not giving me  any option  to  upgrade to   latest version of ubuntu 20.04 .
I am currently  working on ubuntu 18.04 .Please  let me  know   if  there is  a workaround

Comment: The 'taps' for upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS do not open (unless forced) until Ubuntu 20.04.1 is released (actually a number of days after ISO release). This is normal behavior as LTS users usually want stability, so the delay is beneficial (*ensuring stability*)  Currently you can force by adding a '-d' (development) tag to `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Possibly helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059924/should-i-be-offered-the-option-to-upgrade-to-18-04-1