# Focal upgrade availability

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

Does anybody know when Focal will be available to upgrade from Bionic (using Software Updater) on production box?
do-release-upgrade states that upgrade not yet available for production machines. I'm not interested in STS Ubuntu versions. I've downloaded Focal from ubuntu.org and createda Startup on a usb thumb drive. Should I use this to upgrade or wait for Software Updater to give the option of upgrading to Focal?

Comment: I would recommend waiting if you are not in a hurry. However, it can take a few weeks until the update is available to you. What I understand is that Canonical will not enable all the installations to update *at once*. The updates are spread to several weeks.

Comment: @FedonKadifell I'm not so much in a hurry as interested in having a smooth upgrade. Is there any schedule or target date for 20.04.1 to be available by Software Updater?

Comment: I should also have said that I want the .1 version of 20.04 (not the .0 version).

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate link?  It contains links to the *official* Ubuntu 20.04 release schedule, links to the delay notice.. mention of the key word *after* used in official notices from Canonical/Ubuntu, plus *scant* mention of two issues with the upgrade in this cycle (two obvious ones anyway).  PS: If you have the 20.04 & fully-upgrade your system you'll be using 20.04.1 anyway, and Canonical/Ubuntu have released a guide on upgrading without waiting if you'd prefer not to wait https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today

Comment: I looked at the duplicate link but it didn't give  atarget date for using Software Updater.
I've looked at the web page of Ubuntu's upgrade instructions and tried sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3 --allow-third-party but that gave the warning about production machines.

Comment: There is no target date, as the decision on turning on the *taps* for upgrade hasn't been reached. The decision is made when it's deemed as *stable* as it can be, as it's assumed LTS users want to ensure stability, so the decision is not hurried in any way.  Please also refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059924/should-i-be-offered-the-option-to-upgrade-to-18-04-1

Comment: They seem to be taking their time, which is probably good.  They might have found some bugs that make upgrades go bad at this time.  The point .01 should be available to download as an ISO and install now.

Comment: I asked about updating using Software Updater. I already had downloaded 20.04.1 iso.

Comment: FYI:  The scheduled date refers only to the release of the ISO itself (intended for new installs). When the *taps* get turned for upgrades is only ever listed as occurring *after* that milestone (with every intention of it occurring before the 20.04.2 though [added complexity due to two options of hardware stacks; GA or HWE], but that's still awhile ahead of us)

Comment: See this: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604

Comment: What is going on in Canonical? Is it yet another delayed activity due to the Covid-19 excuse? There still appears to be no date as to when the taps will be turned on for upgrade from Bionic to Focal.

Comment: The official statement is just as it is every LTS release. It'll occur **AFTER** the release of 20.04.1.  These complaints occur every LTS cycle....  It's not running late yet; it's a big change with Qt4 now EOL & everything gone from *focal*, `python2` now EOL & likewise gone from *focal* (main anyway) etc...    Canonical are working to ensure LTS users have **stability** as LTS users usually prize that

Comment: I just looked at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604. The only upgrade blocker is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1891680